# String array: search for text, return line number of first occurrence

Tags: c#, arrays, line-numbers

In my string array, I want to look up some text and return the the line number of the first occurrence as an int.

This is working;

```
public static int LookUpLineNumber(String[] item, string TextToLookUp)
{
    int m;
    for (m = 0; m < item.Count(); m++)
    {
        if (item[m].Contains(TextToLookUp))
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return m++;
}
```

However, I am wondering if there is any way to optimize it for efficiency and length?

**Speed comparison:**
*(average time on 10.000 runs with an string array of size 10.000)*

1. Using my code:

   - 1,259ms
2. Using Habib's code: `Array.FindIndex<string>(item, r => r.Contains(TextToLookUp));`

   - 0,906ms

Comment: How many items will be in `String[] item`? Premature optimization is bad optimization. I also don't see any reason why this method would be slow.

Comment: How do you find line number in `string[]`?

Comment: you can use Array.BinarySearch

Comment: Is each string a line?

Comment: Do you need to match within anything or exact match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current solution looks OK. You can have `return m;` instead of `return m++`.

If you want to shorten your code you can use [`Array.FindIndex<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.findindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like:

```
public static int LookUpLineNumber(String[] item, string TextToLookUp)
{
    return Array.FindIndex<string>(item, r => r.Contains(TextToLookUp));
}
```

Not really sure if it would give you any performance gain.

Comment: It anything, that is probably slightly slower. Would need to test that though

Comment: @Simon, Can't really say without a proper test. But what ever performance difference is there, it would be negligible. That is why I said it is just a short code.

Comment: This is what I was gonna suggest

Comment: It does exact same `for` loop internally, with additional parameter checks: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs#1132

Comment: @Habib I agree. It's just lambda's tend to add a little overhead, but not much. It is more concise, I agree.

Comment: @Simon So I did a performance test with both mine and Habib's methods.

Average time on 10.000 runs with an string array of size 10.000:

Using my code: 1,259ms; Using Habib's code: 0,906ms.

Comment: Ok, fair enough, I believe you. Would be interesting to know what it's doing under the covers. That's a much more marked difference than I would have thought. Did you try a regex instead of the contains? That *may be* faster, but again, you would have to try it and see.

Comment: Also see Max's comment below. IndexOf may be faster

Comment: @Simon, I would never use Regex for a simple contain, faster or not, It won't be readable, and even if it turns out to be faster *(which I doubt)*, it won't be readable enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this multiple times, a suffix tree built out of the array would be the fastest approach:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree

However, if you are not re-using the array, then I think the approach you have is likely fastest, short of using a regex to do the contains, which *may be* faster if the regex is pre-compiled.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the following :-

```
Array.FindIndex(item,i=>i.Contains(TextToLookUp));
```

The above would work even if it is not sorted.

The above can be further optimized by using `IndexOf` operations instead of `Contains` and passing `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase`. Then you will have to compare it against 0.